# Hydra: How to express None in config files?

Tags: python, fb-hydra

I have a very simple Python script:

```py
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf


@hydra.main(version_base="1.3", config_path=".", config_name="config")
def main(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    if cfg.benchmarking.seed_number is None: 
        raise ValueError()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

And here the config file:

```
benchmarking: 
  seed_number: None
```

Unfortunately, the Python script does *not* raise an error. Instead, when I print the type  of `cfg.benchmarking.seed_number`, it is `str`. How can I pass `None` instead?

Comment: What value is `cfg.benchmarking.seed_number` being set to? `"None"` or something else? Does hydra document how it's config (yaml?) file is parsed?

Comment: You should use the word 'null' instead of None in the configuration file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try null:

```yaml
benchmarking: 
  seed_number: null
```

Comment: Thanks - I've been using this stuff for years and didn't think you could!

Answer (score 2):

In YAML format, it represents None as a string ("None").

To pass None as the value instead, you can replace it with !!null

```
benchmarking:
seed_number: !!null
```

Using **!!null** in the YAML configuration, it explicitly represents a null value.

But as this configuration is loaded into the Python, cfg.benchmarking.seed_number will be **None** instead of a **string**.